# How to avoid unwanted alignment of components when clicking in the Form Designer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using Embarcadero Delphi 10.3 Version 26.0.36039 on Windows 10.

**Step 1**: place aligned Edit and Button controls on the Form. (Edit.Top = 42)

**Step 2**: Move the Edit down 2 points (Edit.Top = 44)

**Step 3**: Click on the Edit. Bam! The control has moved two points up (Edit.Top = 42)

How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Align_to_Grid and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Form_Designer

Comment: Thanks, David. I have already looked into these links. However, turning off the "Snap To Grid" did not help. 
In addition, I do not observe such a problem at another workstation (Windows 7, Embarcadero Delphi XE).

Comment: Just clicking a control (without moving the mouse cursor a single pixel!) shouldn't move it. Do you have any extensions installed in the IDE?

Comment: I remember to having seen this behavior on High-DPI systems.

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly this has been reported as bug several years ago. And as Uwe Raabe mentioned I also believe the problem appeared on HIGH-DPI systems with OS Font scaling being set to anything but 100%. But I'm not sure of this.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the High-DPI was the key. [Troubleshooting DPI Virtualization and DPI-aware applications, in Windows Vista and Windows 7
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080380/troubleshooting-dpi-virtualization-and-dpi-aware-applications-in-windows-vista)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to disabling ["Snap to Grid"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Form_Designer_Options) and/or "Use Designer Guidelines" in the environment, you can also press (and hold) the Alt key while dragging the component. This will (temporarily) disable the "Snap" feature while you're dragging.

Comment: Yes, I have already checked this option. Unfortunately, disabling "Snap To Grid" does not solve the problem.